# How to close a window in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, xbap

I've got the following code in a window B that is started in its own thread from a window A.

```
view.Closing += (sender, e) =>
{
    view.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    e.Cancel = true;
};
```

When I close window A window B remains in memory and the application doesn't dispose. How should I go forward make sure that the application is shut down when closing window A.

edit: the window B takes a while to load and build that's why the code is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `Application.Exit();`

For WPF: `Application.Current.Shutdown();`

Comment: Yes, it will exit your application.

Answer (score 2):

Basic solution: Window A needs to keep a ref to  Window B and Dispose() it.

You may have to make the Cancel logic in B conditional.

Comment: Application.Current.Shutdown() seems to be working fine. Should I go the (slightly) longer route and do what you propose here?

Comment: Not directly necessary, it might be advisable if you have lots of cleanup to do in the Window(s)